# margin between books not the size in css 3d book cover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this book cover design using css and modernizer:

HTML :

```
<div class="books">
  <div id="book1" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="book2" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="book3" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Fallback styles */
.book {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #333;
  margin: 10px;
}

.book img { vertical-align: middle; }

/*
 *  In order for this to work, you must use Modernizer
 *  to detect 3D transform browser support. This will add
 *  a "csstransforms3d" class to the HTML element.
 *
 *  Visit http://modernizr.com/ for installation instructions
 */

.csstransforms3d  .books {
  -moz-perspective: 100px;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book {
  position: relative;
  -moz-perspective: 100px;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100) rotateY(-3deg);
  outline: 1px solid transparent; /* Helps smooth jagged edges in Firefox */
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:before,
.csstransforms3d  .book:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  height: 96%;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: -1;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 7.5%;
  background-color: #5a2d18;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #333;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:after {
  width: 5%;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100) rotateY(20deg);
}
.csstransforms3d  #book2:before { background-color: #333; }
.csstransforms3d  #book3:before { background-color: #254053; }
```

Now in action width of next+1/last book is elder. i check with more books and see only first book have a normal size. the margin between books is different and not the size

how do can i fix this problem?

demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs5vhenn/)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPr81.png)

Comment: All the bookcovers have the same size at my browser (Firefox ), but your forgot some `perspective` attributes. You added the `-moz-perspective` but you forgot the the ones without prefix

Comment: @Vinc199789: FF 38.0.5 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/CPr81.png

Comment: oh, The books have the same size but there is a different margin-left/right. You didn't told that in your question

Comment: Change your question and say that the margin between books is different and not the size. also add the image you posted. Maybe, the edit will attract new visitors who can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't really need moz prefixes, here. Right now, only unprefixed and webkit prefixed browsers are in use

Second, as Vinc199789 said, you have a perspective set for FF that don't have for the others

```
.csstransforms3d  .books {
    -moz-perspective: 100px;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

should be

```
.csstransforms3d  .books {
    -webkit-perspective: 100px;
    perspective: 100px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

You have the same problem in the book class, you have different styles between different prefixes.

But now, for the real issue: when you are working with this setting, you can choose to give the book series a global perspective or a constant perspective.

## Global pespective

```css
.book {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #333;
  margin: 0px;
}

.book img { vertical-align: middle; }

.books {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.book {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-3deg);
  transform: rotateY(-3deg);
}

.book img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:before,
.csstransforms3d  .book:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  height: 96%;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: -1;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 7.5%;
  background-color: #5a2d18;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #333;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:after {
  width: 5%;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="books">
  <div id="book1" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="book2" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="book3" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

## Constant perspective

```css
.book {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #333;
  margin: 0px;
}

.book img { vertical-align: middle; }

.books {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.book {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-3deg);
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-3deg);
}

.book img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:before,
.csstransforms3d  .book:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  height: 96%;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: -1;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 7.5%;
  background-color: #5a2d18;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #333;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book:after {
  width: 5%;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="books">
  <div id="book1" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="book2" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="book3" class="book">
    <img src="http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/uploads/2012/09/PHPforWebVisualQuickStartGuide.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the different use of the perspective